# Android: Passing touch event to overlapped view

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a Relative layout which has two child layouts. First child is linear layout which is container of a fragment. The fragment has few buttons. The second child is a linear layout which has a View which is blank and transparent. The second child overlaps the first child.The first child is smaller than second child. I want to send touch events from second child to first child so that those buttons on the fragment which first child contains receives click.

I read few posts on internet for solving my problem but could not solve it.

So far i have overriden dispatchTouchEvent of Activity and have tried to detect whether touch is in bounds of first child and if so i do firstChild.onTouch(ev). Actually i just dont know what to do and just trying get it working. So please, help me.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
{
    float x,y,backViewX,backViewY,frontViewX,frontViewY;
    x = ev.getX();
    y = ev.getY();
    frontViewX = frontView.getX();
    frontViewY = frontView.getY();
    backViewX = backView.getX();
    backViewY = backView.getY();

    if(y >= backViewY && y <= (backViewY+backViewHeight))
    {
        if(x >= backViewX && x<=(backViewX+backViewWidth))
        {
                return backView.onTouchEvent(ev);
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Orignal Layout is not the exact as i described but it is little more complex but the concept is same as i described....i am shortning the layout for simplifying things.The frontLayout here overlaps layoutBackFragmentArea.

```
 <RelativeLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/parent"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@color/back_view_background">

    <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/layoutBackFragmentArea"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="@dimen/back_view_height"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:gravity="center_vertical"
         android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/layoutFrontArea"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:gravity="center_vertical"
         android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <View 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

   </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

layoutBackFragmentArea will contain a fragment which has UI which should receive click events.

Comment: Could you post a snippet of what you've tried so far?

Comment: i have posted what you asked